# Workaround for align without using amsmath

Tags: amsmath, align

I'm preparing a manuscript for a journal that demands a style file (`copernicus2.cls`) that's not compatible with `amsmath`. I want to display some aligned equations, but the lack of `amsmath` means I can't use the `align` environment. `eqnarray`'s inconsistent spacing offends me, so I'm wondering if there's some kind of workaround that will let me achieve the effect of `align` without including the `amsmath` package?

Comment: @Dilaton I'd like to continue this in chat but I don't know how. Can you create a room?

Comment: @dilaton I agree with you, I think. I'm on a mobile device so can't easily check all the questions you posted, but generally I think those kinds of high level questions can be detagged, perhaps with some modification in some cases.

Comment: @dilaton I think the definition in emilio pisanty's proposal is going in the direction you suggest. I'll do what I can to make sure it gets there. I'll be busy this weekend too though unfortunately. (Many apologies to the mods here for the irrelevant thread, I just don't want to try and figure chat out while I'm browsing on a phone)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I guess you mean the `copernicus2.cls` provided by the [Biogeosciences](http://www.biogeosciences.net/submission/latex_instructions.html).
The [files](http://www.biogeosciences.net/submission/latex_instructions.html) can be found on there website.

The class file loads the package `txfonts` which must be loaded after `amsmath`.
The package `txfonts` has a mechanism to redefine some internal commands of `amsmath` which `amsmath` doesn't have.

You can load the package `amsmath` as follows to use `align`:

```
\RequirePackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\mathindent0pt
\documentclass[journal abbreviation]{copernicus2}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
1+1&=2 \\
    2&=2
\end{align}
Test
\[1+1=2\]
\end{document}
```

**EDIT**: Set option `fleqn` and `mathindent=0pt`

[image]

Comment: Hm, actually there's still one issue, which is that the copernicus2.cls file aligns equations to the left instead of centering them, but the ones I enter with align are still centered.  What's the best way to make the align ones match the others?

Comment: @Nathaniel: Please see my edit

Comment: sorry for being dense - fleqn still indents the align equation a bit, and putting \setlength{\mathindent}{0mm} (or any other value) in my header doesn't seem to affect it.

Comment: Also, mathindent=0pt as an option for amsmath doesn't work either, it just says it's an unknown option.

Comment: @Nathaniel: I can't understand your problem. I will add an image of my output.

Comment: Ah, I've got it.  Sorry, I read your edited code several times without noticing the \mathindent0pt line, and was trying to figure out for myself how to set it. I had it after the \documentclass line, so it wasn't working. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: @Nathaniel: No problem.

Answer (score 3):

@Marco, `amsmath` does not load `amssymb`. The problem is two fold.

`copernicus2.cls` load `txfonts.sty` which define various `\XintY` macros which `amsmath` also define. Since `amsmath` define these using `\newcommand` the OP get an error because they are already defined.

This works

```
\documentclass[journal abbreviation]{copernicus2}
\let\iint\relax
\let\iiint\relax
\let\iiiint\relax
\let\idotsint\relax
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
1+1&=2 \\
    2&=2
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Though Marcos solution may be better, because the solution above may use a different font for those integral symbols than the Journal intended.

Comment: Please see my edit (17min ago) ;-)

Comment: better, but the journal should provide a better style (is there still kerning issues with `txfonts`?)

Comment: @Deleif: A user of `copernicus` should send a request to Biogeosciences. The kerning issue is the same as usual ;-)